# How do i create Screen Orientation Awareness in android?

Tags: java, android, layout

How do you detect that the user has changed the orientation of the display screen from portrait to landscape and vice versa?

The Android application must adjust to the new orientation. The system should be sending a change of orientation message to all open applications so that they can adjust. I could not find anything about this in the docs? Sorry if i copy these statement from somewhere else but i'm kinna new ina android/java, can someone guide me along?

Its just one of the Preference screen in multiple tabs i have, but i just want mere change of screen orientation when the phone position changes...

```
public class Tab2Activity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.tab2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will automatically recreate (destroy and then create) your activity when the orientation changes. If you want a special layout for landscape, you can create a special resource file in the `layout-land` folder, which will be loaded after the activity is recreated.

On the other hand, if you want to override the default behavior so that you can do something custom when the orientation changes, you can override the onConfigurationChanged method like so:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //do something if portrait...
    }
}
```

Comment: and @Femi thanks for your reply but if i happen that my screen is just a tab screen with multiple PreferenceActivity which i just wanted the screen to just orientate its position for the cause of the phone position how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29

EDIT: in code (add this to your Activity):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration _newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(_newConfig);
        int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        if(width > height){
                // landscape
        }else{
                // portrait
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With pleasure, this is my recomendation for better run detect orientation when changed device mode. You can use code at bellow, then you will take that what do you want:

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        OrientationEventListener orientationListener =
                new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
                    @Override
                    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                        if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 180) {
                            Log.e(this.toString(), "Orientation Device is POTRAIT");
                            // TODO your action at here when device has been change to POTRAIT mdoe. 
                        } else {
                            Log.e(this.toString(), "Orientation Device is LANDSCAPE");
                            // TODO your action at here when device has been change to LANDSCAPE mdoe.
                        }
                    }
                };
        if(orientationListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
            orientationListener.enable();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use code as a method, you can also use the formula below:

```
public static final void runOrientationChangedService(Context context, OrientationEventListener listener) {
    OrientationEventListener orientationListener =
            new OrientationEventListener(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
                @Override
                public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                    listener.onOrientationChanged(orientation);
                }
            };
    if(orientationListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        orientationListener.enable();
        listener.enable();
    }
}
```

Run the service as a method, then we need a role or callback argument instead.